# how can i create repeating section in sharepoint site?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010, repeater, sections

In my sharepoint site I have a section that need repeat 'n' time.

This section get information from a list.

Now I want get number of rows from list and repeat my section for each row.

I can get Data and number of list's row but I can't repeat my section.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can do this is to build a [Visual Web Part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg413295%28v=office.14%29.aspx), extract the data using [Sharepoint Object Model](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/Ravish001/introduction-to-sharepoint-object-model/), and render it using a repeater or any other data list control.

A different method is to use the [content query webpart with some customised xsl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb447557%28v=office.14%29.aspx), only recomended if you are an xsl die hard and are prepared to endure a bit of pain.

Yet another method, if you are a client side wiz, is to use the [REST api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569%28v=office.15%29.aspx) together with some jquery magic to build the view as you want, or alternatively instead of the Rest API you can use web services together with jquery [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/)

Comment: thanx @Luis. 

I use SPServices for getting data and number of rows.
then in a Loop section [with JQuery] I added my html code.

it work fine.